# Update Optiplex gx520 bios

Tags: bios, dell-optiplex

im trying to update the bios on an optiplex gx 520. Ive tried looking for instructions but im still confused.

i downloaded the bios update from dells website.

I currently cannot boot into windows to run the .exe, is there a way that I can put the .exe on a flash drive and boot to the flash drive to update the bios?

Answer (score 0):

According to Dell's web site:

> This file format consists of a BIOS executable file. The Universal
>   (Windows/MS DOS) format can be used to install from Windows XP,
>   Windows 2000, NT, Windows 9X, Windows ME or a MS DOS environment.

Use a bootable disk to get to a command prompt to run this file.

Comment: bootdisk.com has them for download.